# Does gcc support multi-line raw string literals in macro definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

I want to put a constant json string in a **header** file, so that it can be used and also viewed by other sources. I want to use raw string literals in C++11, because it looks clear and pretty. However, i have tried gcc 4.8.5/gcc 4.9.2 to compile the following code using `gcc -std=c++11 test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

/* works, but looks ugly */
#define STR_a \
"{ \n\
    \"AAA\": \"a\", \n\
    \"BBB\": \"b\" \n\
}"

/* works with VS2017, not works with gcc */
#define STR_b \
R"({
    "AAA": "a",
    "BBB": "b"
})";

/* works, but must use 'extern const'/'static' in header files */
const char *STR_var = 1 + R"(
{
    "AAA": "a",
    "BBB": "b"
})";

int main()
{
    const char *s = STR_b;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

However, i get compile errors:

```
   

test.cpp:16:1: error: unterminated raw string
 R"({ 
 ^
test.cpp:19:3: warning: missing terminating " character
 })";
   ^
test.cpp:19:1: error: missing terminating " character
 })";
 ^
test.cpp:29:2: error: stray ‘R’ in program
```

If i add backslashs, gcc works:

```cpp
#define STR_b \
R"({ \
    "AAA": "a", \
    "BBB": "b" \
})";
```

But it shows wrong string:

```
{ \
    "AAA": "a", \
    "BBB": "b" \
}
```

Is it an implementation-defined feature? Does higher versions of gcc support this feature?

---

Edit:

I downloaded and compiled gcc 7.3.1 source, then tried again for my test code; however, gcc7.3.1 reports the same errors like gcc 4.X. I give up, and decide to continue to use `static const char *`. The answer of @lyang is also good, it opens my minds.

Comment: Raw strings are a feature of the C++ compiler that the preprocessor (probably) isn't privy to. However, I've found a few subtle differences between different preprocessors here and there, so you might find one that'll let you do it, but it certainly wouldn't be standard. The "ugly" way you showed is the only safe way.

Comment: What's wrong with using `static const char*` variables here?

Comment: @Frank Yes, i have used `static const char *` variable in the header file so far, but i prefer raw string. If a new version of gcc supports this feature, i will upgrade gcc and then replace the part of code right away.

Comment: @TaoSfqh that's an orthogonal concern. You can assign a raw string to a `static const char*`. Now, if you meant string literals, then you are misguided. Duplicated identical literals will lead to the same result, just with more work for the compiler.

Comment: @Frank Sorry for my unclear expression.  `static` makes any source file including this header have one copy of this variable, i try to avoid this defect. If i use `extern  const char *` instead, i have to put the constant string into one source, but i expect people can see it in the header file.

Comment: @TaoSfqh That "defect" is trivially optimizable away by the compiler: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cEKrcJ, and not worth poluting your global namespace with macros over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Latest update 4/4/2019**

I recently heard about [Cog](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/) and think that it could be a better solution than m4. It uses python for preprocessing, making the code more readible, as shown below (easily support quote inside string):

```
#include <cstdio>

/*[[[cog
import cog, re

def escape_raw(s):
    s = re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', s) # escape backslash first
    s = re.sub(r'"', r'\"', s) # escape quotes
    return re.sub(r'\n', r'\\n\n', s) # escape newline last

def cog_define(name, val):
    cog.outl("#define {name} {val}".format(name=name, val=val))

STR_test = r"""{
    "AAA": "a",
    "BBB": "b",
    "contain \" quote": "c"
}"""

cog_define("STR_test", escape_raw(STR_test))

]]]*/
//[[[end]]]

int main()
{
    const char *s = STR_test;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
#include <cstdio>

/*[[[cog
import cog, re

def escape_raw(s):
    s = re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', s) # escape backslash first
    s = re.sub(r'"', r'\"', s) # escape quotes
    return re.sub(r'\n', r'\\n\n', s) # escape newline last

def cog_define(name, val):
    cog.outl("#define {name} {val}".format(name=name, val=val))

STR_test = r"""{
    "AAA": "a",
    "BBB": "b",
    "contain \" quote": "c"
}"""

cog_define("STR_test", escape_raw(STR_test))

]]]*/
#define STR_test {\n
    \"AAA\": \"a\",\n
    \"BBB\": \"b\",\n
    \"contain \\\" quote\": \"c\"\n
}
//[[[end]]]

int main()
{
    const char *s = STR_test;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

==============================================================

Have you tried GNU's [m4](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/m4_4.html)?

This is kind of hacky, but the idea is to preprocess a nicer looking version to the ugly version (not using raw string).

Your code will be like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

m4_changecom(`/*', `*/')
m4_define(`ESCAPE_RAW', `"m4_patsubst(`m4_patsubst($1, `"', `\\"')', `
', `\\n\\
')'") /* substitute newline and double quote with escaped version */

#define STR_test ESCAPE_RAW(`{
    "AAA": "a",
    "BBB": "b"
}')

int main()
{
    const char *s = STR_test;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

The ugly `ESCAPE_RAW` macro only needs to define once, and all following "raw string"s can use `ESCAPE_RAW` to generate ugly versions that gcc recognizes.

To preprocess with m4, use command `m4 -P test.cpp`, where `-P` forces the `m4_` prefix on the define statements. The command produces this:

```
#include <cstdio>




#define STR_test "{\n\
    \"AAA\": \"a\",\n\
    \"BBB\": \"b\"\n\
}"

int main()
{
    const char *s = STR_test;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe name your m4 file with `.m4` extension, and use m4 to generate the ugly looking header files.

Comment: Thanks, it's another approach new to me. However, it requires the makefiles to do more work for m4, and also every source including this header (maybe others use this header with my library) must do this work too.

Comment: i tested, but m4 threw a warning: `excess arguments to builtin m4_patsubst ignored`, and printed wrong result.   Besides, my test code is just a simple json string , actually the json may be complex, e.g. a field may contain newlines and escape characters again: `"CCC":"c\"c\nc"`

Comment: @TaoSfqh Not sure why the warning shows up, but for more complex JSON string you need to also escape backslash, i.e. `m4_patsubst($1, \`\', \`\\')`. For your concern about distributing, I guess you can process all the `.m4` files with some commit hook so end user will only see the version with the "ugly" macros.

Comment: @TaoSfqh Actually I have to admit that using m4 with this purpose is very tricky and hard to debug, especially if you want to substitute both newline and backslash correctly. I cannot figure out a correct way to do it yet. Sorry.

Comment: @TaoSfqh I think you might be interested in the lasted update using a python program called cog.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is covered by [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55971), which appears to have a fix implemented in June, 2022. As of writing, the fix is intended to release in GCC 13, and is already available in trunk.

I suspect what happened here was the following rule and accompanying note in [cpp.pre]/1 regarding how to process preprocessor directives:

> The last token in the sequence is the first token within the sequence that is immediately followed by whitespace containing a new-line character. [ *Note:* A new-line character ends the preprocessing directive even if it occurs within what would otherwise be an invocation of a function-like macro. — *end note* ]

I'm guessing GCC was too aggressive with detecting newlines within a preprocessing directive, leading to the behaviour you encountered. When you add backslashes, the letter of the spec says that the lines are spliced into one really early on, but then this splicing is reverted in a raw string literal when lexing the raw string literal token. It seems that avoids the newline detection, but of course produces a different raw string literal than the one you want in the process.